# What algorithms are there to decide when and how to split up computations onto several machines?

Tags: algorithm, cloud, cluster-computing

Suppose you have 4 computing tasks A, B, C, D. Some depend(in the following written as `->`) on others as a prerequisite. E.g. B`->`A means that I have to compute A first before I can start computing B.

The dependency is as in the tree below, so D`->`B`->`A and C`->`A

```
A
|\
B C
|
D
```

If I decide to do all the computations on a single machine, the total computation time will be(assume each machine has only a single core/thread):

```
Total time = t(A) + t(B) + t(C) + t(D)
```

I could also split them up onto two machines:

```
Machine1      Machine2
A              A
|              |
B              C
|
D
```

In this case the total time will be shorter(I'm neglecting the overhead involved in splitting up the computation):

```
Total time = Max(t(A) + t(B) + t(D), t(A) + t(C))
```

Notice that in this case A has to be computed twice, once on each machine. So although we have a shorter total time we wasted computing resources.

Splitting up would always be good if we wouldn't be competing with other users that use the same cluster. So depending on the load it might or might not be a good idea to split.

I'm looking for two algorithms:

1. how to split up computations onto several machines? It would mean analysing the dependency tree and figuring out the independent branches.
2. when to split up the computations onto several machines? We need to take into account the nr. of machines, the current load, which computations would have to be repeated(in the example above it would be A) and how costly the repeated computations are. E.g. in the example above consider that A could take 1 sec or 50 seconds.

Comment: http://cse.unl.edu/~ylu/csce896/papers/p11-meng.pdf

Comment: Can't you split after calculating A?

Comment: @maraca All the computations are done on a grid, not on the computer doing the splitting. So at the moment what you propose would not be possible to do. It would imply sending A to the Grid getting the response back and sending this together with the data for the following computations back to the grid. Not doable yet, but definitively I could investigate this.